# Marketing Cloud SQL Query - Removing Rows containing certain values

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

So I'm trying to query data extension Data123, and I want to grab all rows where Email_Address doesn't contain 'TEST'. I thought the proper syntax would be Select * from Data123 Where Email_Address NOT LIKE '%TEST%'. However, when I input this, I get

" An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Name'."

Not sure what the correct syntax is here? Unfortunately, I do not understand the SFMC SQL documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: The query would be slow running, but your syntax looks fine. Is this the full body of your query or is this a redacted version? The error message doesn't seem fit.

Comment: So this is my full original query:Select * From SendSummaryDER2SQL 
Where Email Subject 
NOT LIKE '%TEST%' Failure: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Subject'

Comment: I guess it's expecting the column 'Email Name' to be a Boolean value? At least from what I gather, it's saying that LIKE ... is a function that I can only utilize with Boolean values?

Comment: Try putting square brackets around the "Email Subject" field to escape the space in the field name.

Comment: That worked @Macca ! Thank you so much. So SFMC requires column headings to be inside [] , while values should be inside ' ' ? I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Macca answered my question. My syntax looked fine, I just needed to input brackets around my Column name. So the correct query would be Select * From TableName Where [Column Name] NOT LIKE '%TEST%'